# JavaScript: Using Object Literals to Save Time and Work during content Manipulation

Tags: javascript, javascript-objects

If we write this-

```
var myVariable={
   propertyA:"valueA",
   propertyB:"valueB",
}
```

We can call `propertyB` like this-

```
myVariable.propertyB
```

Keeping this in mind, when we write-

```
document.getElementById('myDiv').style.visibility='hidden'
```

We can write this, like this-

```
document.getElementById('myDiv').style={
                                   visibility:'hidden',
                                   display:'inline',
                                 }
```

Well, if that was correct then we may do this-

```
document.getElementById('myDiv')={
       innerHTML:'this is a div',
       style:{
         visibility:'hidden',
         display:'inline',
       }
}
```

Now, if those were correct then may be this also-

```
document={
  getElementById('myDiv'):{
    innerHTML:'this is a div',
    style:{
      visibility:'hidden',
      display:'inline',
    }
  }
  getElementById('mySpan'):{
    innerHTML:'this is a span',
    style:{
      visibility:'visible',
      display:'table',
    }
  }
}
```

So, how many of them are wrong/correct? If wrong, why and what was wrong? Can you give me any more information related to this?

Thanks in advance :-)

Comment: Id love to answer this, but you really ought to do your own homework.

Comment: don't think that i am taking an advice not asking someone to do something for me.

Comment: Start by looking at `document.__proto__` and `document.getElementById('myDiv').__proto__`, and compare that to `({}).__proto__`.

Comment: @MattBall explain more clearly i am new to js, and not much intelligent too.

Answer (score 3):

All Javascript objects are hashes, and vice versa -- so your assumption is based in truth.  However, Javascript assignment is a replacement operation, not augmentation.  This can be easily seen in a simple example:

```
obj = { a: { b: 2 } }
obj.a.b   // => 2
obj.a = { c: 3 }
obj.a.c   // => 3
obj.a.b   // => undefined
```

Barring magic in the implementation of a `HTMLElement`'s `style` attribute, assigning to it will not simply merge the values.  The further up that chain you assign, the more damage you do.

Finally, any value given before a `:` in an object literal is expected to be either a string or a bareword (which will be quoted) -- variables and function calls (like `getElementById('mySpan')`) cannot be used as keys in an object literal.

You can, however, get the behavior you were looking for with something like the following:

```
var divStyles = document.getElementById('myDiv').style;
var styles = { visibility:'hidden', display:'inline' };

for (key in styles) {
  if (styles.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
    divStyles[key] = styles[key];
  }
}
```

The overhead may or may not be worth it, depending on how many properties you are changing.

Comment: You gave a good answer but i asked, what is wrong/correct? Are all of them correct they can save a lot of time.

Comment: As I explained, none of your object assignments work the way you've described them.

Answer (score 1):

Whenever you do

```
myVar.someObject = { ... }
```

You completely override "someObject", throwing away any poperties it had before the assignment.

```
var myvar = { obj: {a:1, b:2} };
myvar.obj = {a:3}

console.log(myvar.obj.a) // 3; ok
console.log(myvar.obj.b) // undefined; oh no!
```

Comment: explain more clearly i am new to js, and not much intelligent too.

Comment: @amnotiam i think you are right the answer is something different than the question

Comment: @Jashwant: Apparently everything starting at the text *"Keeping this in mind..."* Nothing from that point forward will work as expected. OP was asking whether the code is correct, and if not, why.